# How to use javascript variable when using opener.parent?

Tags: javascript

How do I use the variable in this case?
It works in alert, and normal conditions.
But how do I use it in this case? I think the "dot" destroys the function..?

```
<script langauge="javascript">
function post_value2(formName){
opener.document.formName.viamedlem.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
//alert(formName);  //alerts cookies
self.close();
}
</script>
```

I have tested with +formName+, {formname} and the only thoughts I have right now is to convert it to an object, but it sounds a bit overkill for a simple thing as this..?

```
<input ... onclick="post_value2('cookies');">
```

Comment: `language="javascript"` is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript"`  for HTML4 or just `<script>` for HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bracket notation to access an object by its name/key

```
opener.document.forms[formName].viamedlem.value
```

Or add an `id` attribute to the form/field and use this to get the DOM node

```
opener.document.getElementById(...)
```